# How to Unlock Newly Created Folder in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I am using TFS 2010 in my project,and have added some Existing Projects in my solution and i have shelved the changes(all the added files are checked out).   When my team member unshelved the changes they got error like

**Info.cs locked for Check out by username in workspacename**

this continues for all my newly added files.

is this permission problem,because when i Right click the newly added folder, **Unlock,Lock,Properties** options are disabled.

I want to remove the lock and my team member also to be able to unshelve and checked in.

Can anyone please help to unlock the files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c72skhw4.aspx, or you can use the Sidekicks for this http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

Comment: http://bloodsweatandbugs.blogspot.in/2009/01/how-to-unlock-file-in-team-foundation.html can refer this also

Comment: hi, when i check out other files and shelved its working fine.problem happened only for added Existing Projects.